# Combining SQL `raiserror` with `select` in C#

Tags: c#, sql, raiserror, executereader

I want to know if there is a way of using both SQL `raiserror` and retrieving the selected result in C#. `ExecuteReader()` in C# will throw an exception when `raiserror` occurs, but I still want to use the reader to capture any data returned.

Below is a simplified example. If this is not possible I will use `raiserror` for general cases and `select` for specific cases.

```
if (some-error)
begin
    select  @Message = 'ERROR: script made a booboo',
            @State = 'State Info'
    raiserror (@Messsage, 16, 1)
    goto exit_sp
end

exit_sp:
    select  @Message 'Message', @State 'State'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lower the severity to 10 or below (from memory) it will not raise an exception, but will be available via the `InfoMessage` [event on the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx). Note, however, that because of how TDS works, you should ensure that you `Read()` etc to the *end* of ***all*** results; for example, if you have multiple `select`s and **then** a `raiserror`, and you only read the first `select` before dropping the data-reader, there is a chance you won't see the message (the TDS will be killed).